# Extend a community module - Inchoo Facebook Login

Tags: module, magento-1

I would like to extend a community module. The one I am refering to is the [Inchoo Facebook Login](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/facebook-connect-magento-extension/).

This module has a class called `Inchoo_Facebook_Block_Template` and one of the classes methods is:

```
public function getRequiredPermissions()
{
    return json_encode('email,user_birthday');
}
```

I would like to create a module that "extends" (is that the correct term in Magento?) this class and changes what the above method returns. At the moment I am editing the method directly to accomplish my task and changing the above method to:

```
public function getRequiredPermissions()
{
    return json_encode('email,user_birthday,friends_birthday,user_photos,friends_photos');
}
```

The module I am creating should add extra Facebook permissions to the Facebook Login module but not edit its contents.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After adding a dependency your `etc/modules/*.xml` file

```
<depends>
    <Inchoo_Facebook/>
</depends>
```

You should be able to safely rewrite the class from your own module:

**config.xml**

```
<config>
    <global>
        <blocks>
        <extension>
                <class>Your_Extension_Block</class>
        </extension>
            <inchoo>
                <rewrite>
                    <template>Your_Extension_Block_Template</template>
                </rewrite>
            </inchoo>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

**Your/Extension/Block/Template.php**

```
class Your_Extension_Block_Template extends Inchoo_Facebook_Block_Template 
{
    public function getRequiredPermissions()
    {
        return json_encode('email,user_birthday,friends_birthday,user_photos,friends_photos');
    }
}
```

Comment: I just had to change the <inchoo> elements to <facebook> and this worked great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sander's answer will put you on the right track if you want to keep your improvements to yourself. However since we all love open source I suggest you send the guys at Inchoo a pull request with your changes. If you make it optional through a new setting I am fairly sure they would include it.

You can find the code for the Facebook extension [on Github](https://github.com/ivanweiler/Inchoo_Facebook).

Also take a look [at the Social Connect extension from them](https://github.com/Marko-M/Inchoo_SocialConnect) which combines the Facebook extension with a range of other login options (currently Google and Twitter).

Comment: Here is another module that offers twitter, Yahoo and Gmail along with the Facebook login option.
http://www.fmeaddons.com/magento/social-facebook-twitter-login-extension.html